# Does Spring Security support multi factor authentication?

Tags: spring-security

Has anyone tried it?

Can this be used for sites that require high security like banking and financials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cloudseal](http://www.cloudseal.com) plugs into spring security and offers single sign on and multi factor authentication using hard and soft tokens.

Comment: Did CloudSeal change its name or go out of business?  The CloudSeal domain no longer exists.

Comment: @DerekMahar please see https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/java-spring-security

Comment: So Cloudseal is now Auth0?

Answer (score 2):

> Does Spring Security support multi factor authentication?

It doesn't support this out-of-the-box, but the SpringSecurity framework is very flexible, and I'd be amazed if you couldn't implement this functionality.

---

**UPDATE (2020-01-14)**

There is a "current" issue for adding MFA support to Spring Security:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/2603

Here are some examples of MFA that can be implemented with Spring technology:

- [Two Factor Auth with Spring Security](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-two-factor-authentication-with-soft-token) - a tutorial by Baeldung.
- OKTA - [Secure Your Spring Boot Application with Multi-Factor Authentication](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/06/12/mfa-in-spring-boot).  (Uses SpringBoot)

Answer (score 2):

There is a specific exception (`InsufficientAuthenticationException`) which you should probably use for this. You'd need to provide an implementation of `AccessDecisionManager` which threw this exception if the first level of authentication passed, and a custom `ExceptionTranslationFilter` which recognised it and forwarded the user to the next stage of authentication.

Comment: @Nilesh: It's not kludgey. It's just that it doesn't do it out of the box, so you need to use the defined extension points to add it.

Comment: uh. throwing around exceptions for normal control flow doesn't seem right to me...

Comment: I just implemented this using a custom AccessDecisionVoter and custom AuthenticationEntryPoint. ExceptionTranslationFilter didn't need to be modified because it passes the exception to the AuthEntryPoint, which can return a different response if InsufficientAuthenticationException was thrown.